# What is the exact meaning of delegate() method in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am pretty new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I am working on a SharePoint project.

I have the following doubt related to this method in my code:

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
                DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see this code is executed into **delegate() {...}** "block":

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
{
    SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
    DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
});
```

What exactly means this **delegate()** method?

Reading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate

it seems to me that it somethings like a way to declare an "anonymous" method where the implementation of this method is the code into the **{...}** block.

Is this the correct interpretation or am I missing something?

In case it is correct what is the pourpose of this **delegate()** method? Why I am not declaring the code into a classic method? What is it exact pourpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation you referred to, the `delegate` keyword is used for two purposes:

- To declare a delegate type
- To create an *anonymous method* which is converted into a delegate instance

Now you *could* write all the code in an anonymous method in a regular method and then use a method group conversion to create a delegate instance, but that can often be annoying - particularly if you want to use any local variables or parameters in the anonymous method.

So that's why you'd use an anonymous method - or in anything from C# 3 onwards, you're more likely to use a *lambda expression* instead.

Consider how you'd have to create the delegate in your example if you *didn't* use an anonymous method or lambda expression. You'd need to write something like this:

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        // Note: try/catch removed as it's pointless here, unless you're
        // *trying* to obscure the stack trace in case of an exception
        JobDeletionHelper helper = new JobDeletionHelper(properties);
        // Note that we're using a method group conversion here - we're not
        // invoking the method. We're creating a delegate which will invoke
        // the method when the delegate is invoked.
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(helper.DeleteJob);
    }
}
// We need this extra class because the properties parameter is *captured*
// by the anonymous method
class JobDeletionHelper
{
    private SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties;

    internal JobDeletionHelper(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public void DeleteJob()
    {
        // This is the code that was within the anonymous method
        SPWebApplication parentWebApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
        DeleteExistingJob(JobName, parentWebApp);
    }
}
```

If you're asking about the purpose of delegates themselves, that's a slightly bigger topic - but in a nutshell, it's the ability to represent executable code as an object, so it can be passed to other code to execute. (You can think of a delegate type as being like a single-method interface, if that's useful.)

Comment: Why would one prefer using `SomeMethodAcceptingDelegate( delegate() { ... } )` over `SomeMethodAcceptingDelegate( () => { ... } )`

Comment: @RoyalBg: Usually when I see that, it's because it's in a tutorial written before C# 3.

Answer (score 2):

> it seems to me that it somethings like a way to declare an "anonymous"
>   method where the implementation of this method is the code into the
>   {...} block.

Yes, that is on point!

> In case it is correct what is the pourpose of this delegate() method?
>   Why I am not declaring the code into a classic method? What is it
>   exact pourpose?

Since you mentioned that you came from Java you can think of passing a `delegate(){ ... }` as passing an anonymous class in java to some extent.

In Java, an anonymous class enables you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that **they do not have a name**. Use them if you need to use a local class **only once**.

For example, In Java prior to JDK8 you could do:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {  //<--- implementation
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
             System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
  });
```

or as of JDK8:

```
btn.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));
```

Likewise in C# `delegate () {...}` is allowing you to pass an implementation i.e some behaviour on the fly.

It was common pattern a while back to use `delegate () {...}` but now you're most likely to use a lambda equivalent of `() => { ... }`

---

You may find these posts of interest:

- [when & why to use delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates)
- [Where do I use delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497/where-do-i-use-delegates)