# Func as Variable in a class

Tags: c#

I would like to use a function as a variable for me to assign.

Something like this

Class:

```
public class Func
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Function function { get; set; } //Not sure what type for a func
}
```

Func:

```
public void Click_Event(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
//Some code here.
}
```

List to assign the func:

```
List<Func> funcList = new List<Func>();
Func func = new Func();
func.Name = "Name";
func.Content = "Hello World";
func.function = Click_Event;  //This is what I really want to do.
funcList.Add(func);
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

### Edited

Some of the comment below said that Reflection may cause the performance issue, but I use it and doesn't seen any slow issue currently. I use it when I first start the app only.

This is the sample code I use it.

```
MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("FuncName"); //Or using nameof
btnFunc.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, Delegate.CreateDelegate(Button.ClickEvent.HandlerType, this, method, false));
```

Comment: It's called a `delegate` _a pointer to a function_, check [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm)

Comment: You are looking for a delegate. Something like `Action<object, EventArgs>` or just use an event handler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497/where-do-i-use-delegates

Comment: It looks like you're doing something wrong. What do you need a `List<Func>`.  .Net already provides a `Func` class for you.  A `Func` has an list backed behind it already (altough the you still may want to use a list because messing with the invocation list can cause issues).  But To me it sound like you just want to register a list of funcs with some event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a several research, I have found another way to solve this.
Save the function name as a string instead of as a Action or delegate

Then use `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` and `btn.AddHandler` to use it.

By this way, the function must be public.

Comment: That's really not a great way of doing it, IMO. If the methods you want to use always have the same signature, or one compatible with `EventHandler`, just make it of type `EventHandler`. I'd strongly advise renaming `Func` to something else though, otherwise it will confuse readers who expect `Func` to mean `System.Func`.

Comment: Getting your function by Reflection is less performant than accessing them through a delegate. Renaming the function later is also more difficult with Reflection (if you don't use `nameof(): `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a delegate:

> A delegate is a data structure that refers to a static method or to a
>   class instance and an instance method of that class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.8

Another option to look into would be an [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8) or [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I try using Action for this issue, but how can I bind it with btn.Click?
It throw me an error 'No overload for Action<object,RoutedEventHandler>. Invoke(object,RoutedEventHandler) matches delegate RoutedEventHandler'